# What is the cardinality of a lone element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I know that elements which are not sets do not have cardinality, but hear me out.

Suppose that $A=\{u,\{\{v,w\},x,\{y,\{z\}\}\}\}$. The nesting of the sets allows you to uniquely identify particular elements by there "depth" in $A$. For example $z$ is the only element $e\in^4A$ ($\in^4$ is an abuse of notation meant to suggest that $e$ is an element of an element of an element of an element of $A$).

However, this type of statement is not sufficient for uniquely identifying any element *other than* $z$, as, for example, the set of all $e\in^2 A$ contains $\{v,w\}$, $x$, and$\{y,\{z\}\}$.

It is still possible to distinguish between each of these elements, though; $e\in^2A\ and\ |e|\neq2$ defines $x$, $e\in^2A\ and\ \nexists\ b\in e:|b|=1$ defines $\{u,w\}$, and $e\in^2A\ and\ \exists\ b\in e:|b|=1$ defines $\{y,\{z\}\}$.

The statement used to identify $x$ is true because $x\in^2A$ and $|x|\neq2$, the latter because $x$ is not a set, and therefore cannot have a cardinality of 2. Similarly, $\{y,\{z\}\}\in^2A$, and $|\{z\}|=1$.

Now, since I've used cardinality to differentiate the elements $e\in^2A$ from one another, I should like to define the cardinality of each such element. While this is no problem for the sets $\{u,v\}$, $\{y,\{z\}\}$, and the singleton set $\{z\}\in^3A$, it is an issue for the elements $x$ and $y$. The statement $|x|\neq1$, while true, cannot be evaluated if $x$ does not have cardinality. Since $\{x\}\neq x$, the cardinality of $x$ cannot be 1.

One possibility is that the cardinality of $x$ is 0, but this runs the risk of equating the element $x$ with the empty set, which would violate the axioms of ZFC if $x$ is considered to be a set. On the other hand, you could say that the empty set is the only *set* whose cardinality is zero, and that $x$ is not a set: thus, $|x|=0\not\implies x=\emptyset$. But this runs into the problem of defining what a set *is*.

So, what *is* the best way to define the cardinality of an element? If there isn't one, then is there a good way to describe how a lone element is *unlike* a set, in set theoretic terms?

Comment: Every set except the empty set has elements. And if I understand your question correctly, you imply that $u,v,w,x,y,z$ have no elements. So they must all be the empty set, with cardinality zero. Or am I missing something?

Comment: $u$,$v$,$w$,$x$,$y$, and $z$ are not sets, they are constants, variables, vectors etc. For simplicity's sake, you can treat each of $u$,$v$,$w$,$x$,$y$, and $z$ as a separate real number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ZF(C) and most other set theories, every object is a set, so in particular each of the elements $u,v,w,x,y,z$ in your question are sets, which have cardinalities by virtue of the fact that they are sets.

There are some set theories such as ZFA and NFU that admit [*atoms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) (a.k.a. *urelements*), which are objects that are not sets. In these settings, you would typically not define $|a|$ when $a$ is an atom.

You could define $|a|=0$ if $a$ is an atom, since atoms don't have any elements. In this case, you're right that the sentence $\forall x,\, |x|=0 \Rightarrow x = \varnothing$ is no longer true. When dealing with atoms, though, it is common to have some way of discerning between sets and atoms, e.g. via a unary predicate $S$ or a definition of a class $V$ of (non-atomic) sets, in which case the sentence $\forall x \in V,\, |x| = 0 \Rightarrow x=\varnothing$ *is* true. Thus anything you'd want to prove about sets in a regular set theory without atoms, you just relativise to the class $V$ of all sets.